# How do I count the number of files in HDFS from an MR job?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm new to Hadoop and Java for that matter.  I'm trying to count the number of files in a folder on HDFS from the MapReduce driver I'm writing.  I'd like to do this without calling the HDFS Shell as I want to be able to pass in the directory I use when I run the MapReduce job.  I've tried a number of methods but have had no success in implementation due to my inexperience with Java.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Nomad.

Comment: Please add a short description of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the FileSystem and iterate over the files inside the path.  Here is some example code

```
int count = 0;
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(getConf());
boolean recursive = false;
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> ri = fs.listFiles(new Path("hdfs://my/path"), recursive);
while (ri.hasNext()){
    count++;
    ri.next();
}
```