# How to count number of files under specific directory in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to map-reduce framework. I want to find out the number of files under a specific directory by providing the name of that directory.
e.g. Suppose we have 3 directories A, B, C and each one is having 20, 30, 40 part-r files respectively. So I'm interested in writing a hadoop job, which will count files/records in each directory i.e I want an output in below formatted .txt file:

A is having 20 records

B is having 30 records

C is having 40 records

These all directories are present in HDFS.

Comment: why do you want to create a job for it, can't you simply write a java program for it?

Comment: Easy version: `hadoop fs -ls /dir | grep part-0* | wc -l`

Answer (score 6):

The simplest/native approach is to use built in hdfs commands, in this case `-count`:

```
hdfs dfs -count /path/to/your/dir  >> output.txt
```

Or if you prefer a mixed approach via Linux commands:

```
hadoop fs -ls /path/to/your/dir/*  | wc -l >> output.txt
```

Finally the MapReduce version has already been answered here:

[How do I count the number of files in HDFS from an MR job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344441/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-files-in-hdfs-from-an-mr-job)

Code:

```
int count = 0;
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(getConf());
boolean recursive = false;
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> ri = fs.listFiles(new Path("hdfs://my/path"), recursive);
while (ri.hasNext()){
    count++;
    ri.next();
}
System.out.println("The count is: " + count);
```